# Knex.js migration not working from Github Action

Tags: node.js, knex.js, github-actions

I have this wired issue with Github Action which is deploying NodeJS with Objection.JS ORM. Its working properly and I have written command for it to migrate database.

```
    "migrate": "knex migrate:latest --env production"
```

If I ssh into server and run above command, it works fine, but I have GitHub action which executes same command and it fails. I guess it might be something to do with environment variables. Does command executed from GitHub action can access environment variables or not?

Here's the error in Github Action:

```
out: > knex migrate:latest --env production
135
out: 
136
out: Requiring external module ts-node/register
137
out: Using environment: production
138
err: error: password authentication failed for user "***"
139
err:     at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/***/odin/odin/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:357:11)
140
err:     at Parser.handlePacket (/home/***/odin/odin/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:186:21)
141
err:     at Parser.parse (/home/***/odin/odin/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:101:30)
142
err:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/***/odin/odin/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)
143
err:     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
144
err:     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
145
err:     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
146
err:     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
147
err:     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
148
err: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
149
err: npm ERR! errno 1
150
err: npm ERR! app@1.0.0 migrate: `knex migrate:latest --env production`
```

Here's GitHub action script:

```
 script: |
          cd ~/app/app
          git pull origin master
          npm install --production
          npm run build
          npm run migrate
          pm2 restart digthemes
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a knex problem. Something is wrong with your environment variables, as per error message, either password or user is not set correctly.

With regards to environment variables in GA, see this: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/environment-variables